# Where does the Sefer HaChinuch discuss geometry/"Handassa"?

Tags: number, books-generally

I recall flipping through a Sefer HaChinuch and seeing some geometry diagrams. If I recall correctly, he talks about some mitzva involving fair evaluation of plots of land, and he writes you neeed to know *al handasa* -- geometry -- shapes and angles and the like ("zavit chada", "zavit nitzevet" ...) to do this properly.

Has anyone seen this? Can you help me find it again, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the *mitzva* of honesty in weights and measures: שלא להונות במדות. The highest quality [hebrewbooks version](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=338) has little whitespaces where the pictures you seek should be. In the [lower quality version](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45031&st=&pgnum=198) you can clearly see where the copier just left the pictures out.

And finally, a much clearer [type] version of the same text with absolutely no presumption of leaving space for pictures can be found [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/213458), with the relevant paragraph

> ועוד הרבה ענינים המתבארים בספרי חכמת החשבון והגימטריאות, **שיחלקו בין זוית נצבה לזוית נרווחת וזוית חדה**, ואלו שלש צורותיהן כסדר, ובין משולש שוה הצלעות והמשולש אשר שתי הצלעות בלבד שוות, והוא נקרא משולש שוה השוקים, ובין משולש שאין צלע מכל צלעותיו שוות, והוא הנקרא מתחלף הצלעות, ובין מרובע רבוע שוה למרובע ארוך, ומרובע מעויין כזה ומרובע דומה למעוין כזה וכמה צדדין כיוצא באלו, לא יכיל קלף גדול לרוב הצורות שעשו בזה **בעלי חכמת התשבורת והשיעורין הנקראין אלהנדסא** בענינים אלה. ומכל צד צריכין אנו להזהר הרבה במדידת הקרקעות

Comment: Is Handasa an Arabic word, originally?

Comment: This site answers 'yes': http://www.freeweb.hu/etymological/AEDweb.htm

Comment: So a lot of editions omitted the diagrams ... go figure!

Comment: Many texts I can see actually have: "to differentiate between the right angle (like this), the obtuse angle (like this), and the acute angle (like this)". Leaving in the "like this" that had pointed at the picture, but taking out the picture!